# How to get the javascript variable value in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

```
<textarea id="someTextBox" rows="10" cols="50" onblur="save()"></textarea>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function save()
     {
            var str = document.getElementById("someTextBox").value;

            {{ File::put('app/views/example/email.blade.php', str); }}
      }
   </script>
```

I want to use the textarea value inside my put function,how can i use it their.
Please help me out..

Comment: In short, you can't. Because your textarea is filled after the server side script had executed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717668/why-cant-server-side-and-client-side-scripts-interact I believe what you need is to do AJAX request to save the value.

Comment: Thanks Jofry. But i am totally new to laravel can explain me little more, how can i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is printing the result of writing to a file the (unquoted) string 'str'.

If you want to receive the textarea contents, it must be sent on a request to your script on the server.
Here you have a basic example:

```
<textarea id="someTextBox" rows="10" cols="50" onblur="save()"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
function save()
{
var str = document.getElementById("someTextBox").value;
location.href = 'http://myapp/save?text='+encodeURIComponent(str);
}
</script>
```

Now in Laravel routes you could use this

```
Route::get('save', function() {
    File::put('app/views/example/email.blade.php', Input::get('text'));
    return 'Saved!';
});
```

To do this properly you might want to look into AJAX and sanitizing the input, that's a BAD example.